# Read XML element with XSD of "anyType" and attribute xsi:type="string"

Tags: c#, xml, saml, xmlreader

I'm trying to read an XML document (which is a SAML token, but its not specifically a SAML related problem). The XSD (see [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd)) specifies the ***< saml:AttributeValue>*** element on the 3rd last line of the XSD like this:

```
 <element name="AttributeValue" type="anyType" nillable="true"/>
```

It says it can be ***anyType*** which is fine.

But the actual XML has tried to specify the namespace and type and my XMLReader is struggling to read it before its not formatted correctly.

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
   <saml:Attribute Name="Town">
      <saml:AttributeValue
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="string">
                Glasgow
      </saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
```

When I try to read the XML using this code...

```
//This code just simulates the XmlReader navigating over the document, rather than a specific function.
var sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
var output = reader.ReadSubTree();
```

I get this error...

```
{"ID4254: The AttributeValueXsiType of a SAML Attribute must be a string of the form 'prefix#suffix', where prefix and suffix are non-empty strings.\r\nParameter name: value"}
```

This is thrown by the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlAttribute class, see the code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/Tokens/SamlAttribute.cs,138)

I believe it is the format of the ***xsi:type="string"*** which is causing a problem. If I include ***xs:*** in the type attribute of ***xsi:type="string"*** (see below), it seems to work fine.

```
      <saml:AttributeValue
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="xs:string">
                Glasgow
      </saml:AttributeValue>
```

1. Which is valid XML? ***xsi:type="string"*** or ***xsi:type="xs:string"***
2. Am I missing a namespace reference?

(This XML message is generated by a third party, so I can't change it and want to know if its valid or not).

***Update***

The root element does contain the following namespace references:

```
<Request xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
xmlns="http://thirdparty.co.uk/schema">
```

3. I presume from this, the default namespace is "http://thirdparty.co.uk/schema"??

Comment: Could you please post the actual code throwing the error? Currently it's not reproducible with the simulated reader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply with scope of the type value you're using. As per your last update in question the default schema is `http://thirdparty.co.uk/schema`.

Considering scenario:

```
 <saml:AttributeValue
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="string">
                Glasgow
 </saml:AttributeValue>
```

means the parser will try to find the `string` type in default schema where ofcourse `string` is not defined.

Now when you change it to `xs:string` means you're explicitly telling that look for `string` in namespace alias `xs`. That's why below is the correct one:

```
 <saml:AttributeValue
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:type="xs:string">
                Glasgow
 </saml:AttributeValue>
```

Although the error message you're getting is a validation error which might be applied to strict the usage of namespace alias with value.

Comment: I think you're right - the actual error is a validation error, rather than an XML Reader error. Would would you say the original xs:type="string" is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root xmlns:saml="anything">
<saml:AttributeStatement>
  <saml:Attribute Name="Town">
    <saml:AttributeValue
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:type="string">
      Glasgow
    </saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
</Root>​
```

Comment: I've just updated the question with the namespaces which existed on the root element. There is also a further "saml namespace declaration further down. I believe that the "string" has no prefix because it uses the 'default namespace of the document (or local element?)?

Comment: Every prefix has to be declared.  saml is not declared in your example.  You can validate the xml doing the following : VS menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Paste your xml into window.  Error will show up in the Error view just like any compiler error.